# Jquery.Validate Password Equalto - doesn't display error

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-validate

I am able to set Required = true, min and max lengths but for some reason when i try to set an EqualTo paramater for the PasswordAgain field, the form simply allows Submit even though the passwords do not match.

```
    <section>
        <label class="input login-input">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
                                    <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl01$txtUserName" type="text" id="txtUserName" class="form-control" placeholder="UserName" />
                                </div>
                            </label>
                        </section>
                        <section>
                            <label class="input login-input no-border-top">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></span>
                                    <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl01$txtEmail" type="text" id="txtEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" />
                                </div>
                            </label>
                        </section>
                        <section>
                            <label class="input login-input no-border-top">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span>
                                    <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl01$txtPassword" type="password" id="txtPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" />
                                </div>
                            </label>
                        </section>
                        <section>
                            <label class="input login-input no-border-top">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span>
                                    <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl01$txtPasswordAgain" type="password" id="txtPasswordAgain" class="form-control" placeholder="Password Confirm" />
                                </div>
        </label>
        </section>



<script src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/Content/assets/plugins/sky-forms-pro/skyforms/js/jquery.form.min.js")%>"></script>
<script src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/Content/assets/plugins/sky-forms-pro/skyforms/js/jquery.validate.min.js")%>"></script>

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        $("#form1").validate({
            // Rules for form validation
            rules:
            {
                ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl01$txtUserName:
                {
                    required: true
                },
                ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl01$txtEmail:
                {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                },
                ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl01$txtPassword:
                {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 6,
                    maxlength: 20
                },
                ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl01$txtPasswordAgain:
                {
                    required:true,
                    minlength:6,
                    equalTo:"#ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl01$txtPassword"
                }

            },

            // Messages for form validation
            messages:
            {
                ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl01$txtUserName:
                {
                    required: '* Requires a valid UserName.'

                },
                ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl01$txtEmail:
                {
                    required: '* This is a Required Field.',
                    minlength:  '* Password Min Length of 6 char.'
                },
                ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl01$txtPassword:
                {
                    required: '* This is a Required Field.',
                    minlength: '* Password Min Length of 6 char.'
                },
                ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl01$txtPasswordAgain:
                {
                    required: '* This is a Required Field.',
                    minlength: '* Password Min Length of 6 char.',
                    equalTo: "Please specify the same password as above."
                }

            },

            // Do not change code below
            errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                error.insertAfter(element.parent());
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Please only show the ***rendered*** HTML markup for troubleshooting a client-side issue.  With what you've shown, I can't tell if you have a `name` attribute.  This plugin mandates a `name` attribute and this `name` is the only thing you can use within the `.validate()` method.

Comment: Also, how can your password and password-again fields have two different `minlength` rules?  Regardless, once you get the `equalTo` rule working, you won't need any other rules on the "again" field since it must match the original no matter what.

Comment: FYI - if you're using the `unobtrusive-validation` plugin as part of your ASP framework, then your `.validate()` method will be ignored since the Unobtrusive plugin already called `.validate()`.  It's ASP, and AFAIK, unobtrusive is part of the default and you never mentioned otherwise.

Answer (score -1):

```
 ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl01$txtPasswordAgain:
   { required:true,
     equalTo:"#ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl01$txtPassword"
   }
```

Remove minlength from ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl01$txtPasswordAgain

i hope maybe it works

Comment: Unfortunately, it produces the exact same result.